# Why solr use \ escape special characters not working?

Tags: solr

i want to escape special characters like && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \,

documents say

> Escaping Special Characters
>
> Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax.
>
> The current list special characters are
>
> && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \
>   To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search >for (1+1):2 use the query:
>
> (1+1)\:2

I want to search docs containing [ . I'm sure there is character [ in my docs. Here is the definition of subject:

> field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"

but it doesn't work as the picture shows below

[image]

who can help?

Comment: So what are you trying to search for in your example? Any "subject" field which only contain `[` and nothing more? What is the type of the `subject` field and how is that type defined?

Comment: I want to search content containing [ . I'm sure there is character [  in my content.  Here is the definition of subject <field name="subject" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>